# QDBusAbstractAdaptor vs. QDBusAbstractInterface

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, dbus

When exposing some code to D-Bus using Qt D-Bus bindings, when should one use a Qt Adaptor over a Qt Interface?  I'm having a difficult time understanding how exactly they differ since it seems like they provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qdbusabstractinterface.html, "QDBusAbstractInterface class is the base class for all D-Bus interfaces in the QtDBus binding", while, per http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qdbusabstractadaptor.html, "QDBusAbstractAdaptor class is the starting point for all objects intending to provide interfaces to the external world using D-Bus". So, the former is used in the interface itself, the latter is used to provide the interface, i.e., for "exposing some code to D-Bus" you'd write a class inheriting the adaptor and "define the D-Bus interface it is implementing using the Q_CLASSINFO macro in the class definition" (also a quote from the second of the above URLs).

Answer (score 2):

The consumer is to use the `QDBusAbstractInterface`, while the producer is to use `QDBusAbstractAdaptor`. That is, the adaptor (producer) implements some methods, exposes some properties, and sends some signals, while the consumer calls/receives these things.